# How to check if a primary Key is used as foreign key in an other table?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I'm facing a problem here to create a store procedure. I'm not very good in SQL so apologise for this.

I have a table A which as for primary key as special WBS code like : AIRLINE.PRODUCT.TASK
This table A has also a column Active with Y (for yes) or N (no) values.

I have an other table B which use this key as a foreign key.

My problem is that I want my user to be able to delete my WBS code (primary key for table A) from an interface developp on PowerApps. So if they click on Trash Icon, it will run the store procedure but how am I suppose to say in SQL something like : check if the primary key from A is use as a foreign key in B, if yes set the Active column from table A to N, if the primary key exist but is not use as a foreign key just delete it from A.

Thank you in advance for your time and have a good day.

Antoine

Comment: This looks like a straightforward existence check so I suspect I may be missing something . Please publish what you have so far, (procedure code only)

Answer (score 0):

To check if a table have any FK you can use the below query

```
SELECT * FROM information_schema.REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS WHERE UNIQUE_CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA ='' AND CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA ='' AND (TABLE_NAME IN ('') OR REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME IN ('<table-name>'));
```